# Why cpp tell me 'undefined reference to mtx_init'? I already include the headers

Tags: c, unix, mutex, freebsd

I got some problem when writing a c program on FreeBSD 9.2

I want to use mutex lock to help me control the value of certain variable,

and I read this reference:
http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mutex&sektion=9

I already include these header

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/lock.h>
#include <sys/mutex.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/_mutex.h>
```

but cpp always tell me these:

```
3.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `mtx_init'
3.c:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `mtx_trylock'
3.c:(.text+0xd3): undefined reference to `mtx_unlock'
```

I use this command to compile:

```
gcc 3.c
```

Please help me to find out the problem! Thanks!!!

Comment: Where is those function defined? In another source/object file? In a library? You need to *link* with that source/object file or library.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg IMHO, these are kernel level functions (the link refers to a kernel development man page)

Comment: The section you are referring to is about kernel level mutex functions. Assumed that you are implementing a user space application, and not a kernel module, you need to use user space functions like the `pthread_mutex_` functions (e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init)

Comment: @Andreas And maybe that's why the functions are not available to user-space programs, they are for use in the kernel? To the OP: From user-space use [POSIX threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) and their [mutexes](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, most likely (I am not a FreeBSD developer, but the man page section `9` says "Kernel Interface"...)

Comment: Is it possible to not use pthread related functions? I need to use rfork() (because of the spec), thanks!

Comment: If you want to do synchronization between processes, then you might want to look into named semaphores (see e.g. [`sem_open`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sem_open&sektion=3)).

Comment: includes usually just include declarations, and you need a definition, either in your TU or link to it.

Answer (score 0):

`mtx_init` is a kernel function. Unless you're compiling your code as part of a kernel itself of a kernel module (which you don't as that would require passing whole lot more flags to gcc) you can not use kernel's locking primitives.

For userland code you can use pthreads or number of other libraries. For C++ [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html), or [C++ mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) should do the job.